# Query XML data from a table - Use schema collection?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xsd

I need to re-write an old DTS/SQL2000 process that exports xml data stored as a varchar from a table to an xml file only to read it back and populate some tables such as contract/customer/business activity. I want to query the xml column directly instead but always get Blank or NULL depending on the method I use and I am having a really having a hard time. My latest quick version based on another answer is....

```
 SELECT
    XML_MESSAGE.value('(Transaction_Id/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS TransactionID
FROM dbo.XML_REPOSITORY t
OUTER APPLY t.XML_MESSAGE.nodes('Contract_Interface') AS bm(XMLData)
--OUTER APPLY bm.XML_MESSAGE.nodes('food') AS f(XMLData)
```

However, I have created an Schema collection based on the old xsd files for each collection (contract/customer etc) so the real question is how can I use that to extract the relevant data? A cut down version of the xml is below..

```
<Contract_Interface xmlns="http://company.com/backoffice/types/common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://comapny.com/backoffice/types/common http://dataplace/xmlschemas/Policy_Transaction_Interface_1_1_9.xsd">
  <Transaction_Id>48244272268</Transaction_Id>
  <Source_System_Cd>SystemName</Source_System_Cd>
  <Business_Activity>
    <Contract_Id>169929</Contract_Id>
    <Business_Activity_Type_Cd>01</Business_Activity_Type_Cd>
    <Business_Activity_Type_Desc>New Binder</Business_Activity_Type_Desc>
    <Out_Of_Sequence_Ind>N</Out_Of_Sequence_Ind>
    <Effective_Dt>4/18/2021 12:00:00 AM</Effective_Dt>
    <Expiration_Dt>4/18/2022 12:00:00 AM</Expiration_Dt>
    <Premium_Amt>123678.00</Premium_Amt>
    <Contract>
      <Customer>
        <Customer_Id>45678</Customer_Id>
        <ODS_Customer_Id>6789</ODS_Customer_Id>
        <Insured_Info_Overriden_Cd>N</Insured_Info_Overriden_Cd>
        <Insured_Info_Overriden_Desc>No</Insured_Info_Overriden_Desc>
        <Insured_Nm>Make Money PLC</Insured_Nm>
        <Insured_Address>
          <Address_Line_1>Alex Jones Terrace</Address_Line_1>
          <Address_Line_2 />
          <City_Nm>Houston</City_Nm>
          <State_Cd>TX</State_Cd>
          <State_Desc>Texas</State_Desc>
          <Postal_Cd>77002</Postal_Cd>
          <Country_Cd>US</Country_Cd>
          <Country_Desc>United States</Country_Desc>
        </Insured_Address>
      </Customer>
      <Producer>
        <Producer_Id>33333</Producer_Id>
        <ODS_Producer_Id>1234</ODS_Producer_Id>
        <Producer_No>1234</Producer_No>
        <Producer_Nm>Brokerage Limited</Producer_Nm>
        <Billing_Address_Overridden_Ind>false</Billing_Address_Overridden_Ind>
        <Producer_Billing_Address>
          <Address_Line_1>Suite 1000</Address_Line_1>
          <Address_Line_2>Free Road</Address_Line_2>
          <City_Nm>Hamilton</City_Nm>
          <State_Cd />
          <State_Desc />
          <Postal_Cd>HM11</Postal_Cd>
          <Country_Cd>BM</Country_Cd>
          <Country_Desc>Bermuda</Country_Desc>
        </Producer_Billing_Address>
      </Producer>
    </Contract>
 </Business_Activity>
</Contract_Interface>
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us; we can read lowercase characters just fine thank you.

Comment: The XML you've given us isn't valid, the `Contract` node is never closed. If, however, you have valid XML you need to define your XML Namespace in your query.

Comment: @Larnu Why do you think I am shouting? The only upper case words are DTS and SQL2000??

Comment: *All* of your title was in CAPITALS @MarkS ; it's not now as I [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68481843/revisions) your question.

Comment: Apologies, that must have been an accidental caps lock. I have edited and closed  </Contract> which I must have missed when cutting down the XML to post here. . Would you be able to give me an simple example based on my xml please? I don't have much experience with XML. I have tried something like this but its does not work.WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('Contract' as nsContract)  
SELECT  
    [Contract_Type_Cd]
      ,[Business_Division_Cd]
      ,[Business_Division_Desc]
FROM [dbo].[PTS_XML_REPOSITORY]

Comment: Yes, I've added an answer since you corrected the XML, @MarkS . And it includes an example. If you don't understand it, comment under the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, you need to define your Namespace. This uses a variable, instead of your table, but gives you the overlying idea:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<Contract_Interface xmlns="http://company.com/backoffice/types/common" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://comapny.com/backoffice/types/common http://dataplace/xmlschemas/Policy_Transaction_Interface_1_1_9.xsd">
  <Transaction_Id>48244272268</Transaction_Id>
  <Source_System_Cd>SystemName</Source_System_Cd>
  <Business_Activity>
    <Contract_Id>169929</Contract_Id>
    <Business_Activity_Type_Cd>01</Business_Activity_Type_Cd>
    <Business_Activity_Type_Desc>New Binder</Business_Activity_Type_Desc>
    <Out_Of_Sequence_Ind>N</Out_Of_Sequence_Ind>
    <Effective_Dt>4/18/2021 12:00:00 AM</Effective_Dt>
    <Expiration_Dt>4/18/2022 12:00:00 AM</Expiration_Dt>
    <Premium_Amt>123678.00</Premium_Amt>
    <Contract>
      <Customer>
        <Customer_Id>45678</Customer_Id>
        <ODS_Customer_Id>6789</ODS_Customer_Id>
        <Insured_Info_Overriden_Cd>N</Insured_Info_Overriden_Cd>
        <Insured_Info_Overriden_Desc>No</Insured_Info_Overriden_Desc>
        <Insured_Nm>Make Money PLC</Insured_Nm>
        <Insured_Address>
          <Address_Line_1>Alex Jones Terrace</Address_Line_1>
          <Address_Line_2 />
          <City_Nm>Houston</City_Nm>
          <State_Cd>TX</State_Cd>
          <State_Desc>Texas</State_Desc>
          <Postal_Cd>77002</Postal_Cd>
          <Country_Cd>US</Country_Cd>
          <Country_Desc>United States</Country_Desc>
        </Insured_Address>
      </Customer>
      <Producer>
        <Producer_Id>33333</Producer_Id>
        <ODS_Producer_Id>1234</ODS_Producer_Id>
        <Producer_No>1234</Producer_No>
        <Producer_Nm>Brokerage Limited</Producer_Nm>
        <Billing_Address_Overridden_Ind>false</Billing_Address_Overridden_Ind>
        <Producer_Billing_Address>
          <Address_Line_1>Suite 1000</Address_Line_1>
          <Address_Line_2>Free Road</Address_Line_2>
          <City_Nm>Hamilton</City_Nm>
          <State_Cd />
          <State_Desc />
          <Postal_Cd>HM11</Postal_Cd>
          <Country_Cd>BM</Country_Cd>
          <Country_Desc>Bermuda</Country_Desc>
        </Producer_Billing_Address>
      </Producer>
    </Contract>
 </Business_Activity>
</Contract_Interface>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://company.com/backoffice/types/common')
SELECT bm.XMLData.value('(Transaction_Id/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS TransactionID --Should this not be a int or bigint?
FROM @XML.nodes('Contract_Interface') AS bm(XMLData);
```

Comment: Thanks; that was really useful. The problem now is with the way the data is stored in the table XML_MESSAGE is of the data type TEXT and is prefixed with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Contract_Interface xmlns="http://archinsurance.com/backoffice/types/common (I can't change structure or content)  I get blanks when using the data from the table and feeding it into a xml variable. I have tried inserting into a temp table and storing as xml and even converting and removing the first part but still blanks. Any ideas?

Comment: `text` has been deprecated since 2005, @MarkS ; you should have long stopped using it by now. XQUERY can't be used against `text`, only `xml`; it requires a strongly type XML value. You'll need to explicitly `CONVERT` the column in the query first or fix the design before you can use XQUERY against the column. Though those are separate questions if you are having problems implement that.

Comment: Wow you are fast! :-) I was just editing the comment to make it clearer hopefully. The guidance I have is we can't change anything in the database but I will verify again if that's the case> In the meantime I will ask a new question as advised about using it as is . Thank you

Comment: Also if the name space is different, which it is in your comment, you need to ensure you define the necessary namespace(s). The only one I define above is `http://company.com/backoffice/types/common`, but in your comment you are using a completely different one; that name space won't work with the one in your comment, @MarkS . "Blank"/`NULL` values implies that the problem is the node doesn't exist, not that the `text` value couldn't be converted (as you would get an error, unless you are using `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT`).

Comment: It was the namespace that was the problem. I anonymized the original post and forgot to match the namespace with the real data. Now that I have corrected that it works. Thank you again